# Looping through a form using Javascript (auto login)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm attempting to create an auto-login component that will loop through a given form and find the username and password fields (I'm doing this by using the 'type' attribute since the first "text" type is usually the username and first "password" type is usually the password) and then fill in the username/password values. I know that this won't work for all forms but, this is the only way I can think of (there are many many forms).  Would this approach work?

```
    <script>
for(int i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++)
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "text"){
        document.forms[0].elements[i].value = "someUsername";
        break;
    }
for(int i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++)
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "password"){
        document.forms[0].elements[i].value = "somePassword";
        break;
    }   
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
int i = 0
```

isn't valid JS syntax. Perhaps you meant

```
var i = 0
```

Other than that, your code might work depending on the form you get presented with. You are making the assumption that the login field is the first text field on the first form of the document, which might not be the case.

Perhaps you might consider having an array of login field candidates

```
var loginfieldcandidates=['name','login','username','user','userid'];
```

and instead of filling the first text field, try to find the first text field whose name, lowercased, matches any value of the array.

Comment: this is the kind of help I was looking for! thanks, I've been in Java land for a while

Answer (score 0):

You could try an onload function.

So for example you could add to your `<form>` tag `onload="fillForm()"`

Then you could create your function inside the  tags of your page.

```
  function fillForm(){
  document.getElementById['inputID'].value="etc etc";
  .. etc 

  document.getElementById("formName").submit();
 }
```

This is only a brief outline of 1 way of achieving this!

Just to clarify, this just means that when your form loads up, it will execute the function you have defined in javascript, which in turn, will fill and submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it will do the job. Just run it on page load.